# Jena DELETE and URI

Tags: sparql, jena

I have Jena(2.6.4) and ARQ(2.8.8) and can't delete data from the triple store.
SPARQL request:

```
  DELETE {?doc ?p ?o} 
  WHERE {  ?doc ?p ?o; 
        <http://example#fullName> <file:/c:/1.txt> }
```

This request works fine in Sesame Workbench.

But when I try to issue it from Java with DB2 v.10 RDF triple store nothing happens:

```
       Dataset ds = RdfStoreFactory.connectDataset(store, conn);
       GraphStore graphStore = GraphStoreFactory.create(ds) ;
       UpdateAction.parseExecute(deleteDocumentString, graphStore);
```

The only way I have found - compare strings:

```
       {?doc base:fullName ?fname. FILTER(str(?fname) = "file:/c:/1.txt")
```

Comment: I re-done the test for Jena 2.7.2, ARQ 2.9.2 without DB2. The same results:  DELETE {?doc ?p ?o} WHERE {  ?doc <http:/example.com#fullName> <file:/c:/1.txt>. ?doc ?p ?o} - NO ERRORS and nothing was deleted. To delete I should use this query: DELETE {?doc ?p ?o} WHERE {  ?doc <http:/example.com#fullName> ?fname. FILTER(str(?fname) = "file:/c:/1.txt") ?doc ?p ?o}

Comment: I think the problem is you're expecting a URI, but the value is actually a Literal. I've updated my answer, see below. No idea why this would be different between Jena and Sesame though, unless you used a different version of the data for your test with Sesame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<file:/c:/1.txt>` is not a proper URI (it's not properly absolute, although file: URLs are not very well defined).

The formal defintion of file: URls requires: `file://host/path` and `host` maybe omitted, giving `file:///`.

The SPARQL parser converts it to

You can test this with

```
arq.qparse --file QueryInFile.rq
```

It seems the data loading does not do the same step.  The Jena RIOT parse issues a warning when run from the command line:

```
WARN  [line: 1, col: 46] Bad IRI: <file:/c:/1.txt> Code: 57/REQUIRED_COMPONENT_MISSING in AUTHORITY: A component that is required by the scheme is missing.
```

Best to fix the data.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the problem was in data format - "file:/localhost/c:/data/1.txt". When I changed it to "file://localhost/c:/data/1.txt" it starts working.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what error you get, but given that you are using very old versions of Jena and ARQ, I would suspect that the problem is simply that they don't support SPARQL update requests. I suggest you upgrade to a newer version of Jena (or stick to Sesame :))

**Update** It looks to me as if there is a problem in your data. Your update operation and the query you use both try to treat the value for `fullName` as a URI (because you use URI syntax by placing it in angle brackets, like so:

```
 <file:/c:/1.txt>
```

However, apparently that value does not exist as a URI in your data (since the SELECT query you do does not return it, and the DELETE operation you use with it does not delete anything). Since the version where you do a string-based check *does* work, I suspect that in your data, the value is a Literal, rather than a URI.

The following might work:

```
DELETE {?doc ?p ?o} 
WHERE {  ?doc ?p ?o; 
              <http://example#fullName> "file:/c:/1.txt" . 
}
```

Though the above will only work if the literal value is an untyped literal with no language tag. Otherwise, the alternative you found yourself (using a FILTER condition on the string-value) is a fine way to handle this. Or, of course, modify your actual data, if you want these values to be URIs instead of literals.

Comment: +1 Good point on the upgrade though I suspect the problem likely lies in the IBM DB2 backend and not Jena given a recent question on a similar topic by this OP about deletes not working

Comment: SELECT also DOES NOT WORK for query string:"select ?s  where { ?s <http:/example/com#fullName> <file:/c:/1.txt>}";
(Jena 2.7.2)